# Shortening Enum declarations with aliases possible in C# with using directive

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
namespace A
{
    using ClassB.EnumC = EC;   // I would like to have an eqivalent like this

    public class ClassB
    {
        public enum EnumC
        {
            Entry1,
            Entry2,
            Entry3
        }
   }

   public class Foo
   {
       public void Bar()
       {
            ClassB.EnumC e = ClassB.EnumC.Entry1;

            switch(e)
            {
                case EC.Entry1:
                ...
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

As I know one can make an alias for lengthy typenames, at least this works for classes and interfaces. But it seems not to be possible for simple types likes enums. I want to shorten the lengthy definitions when using an `enum` outside its defining class.

Comment: Does your enum really need to be nested to start with? Avoid nested types where possible...

Comment: Why are you sacrificing readablilty and maintainablilty just to save a couple of seconds? Is there some reason you need to shorten to abbreviations? Obviously if you had a long namespace chain then yes but to shorten the actual name of the type seems foolhardy to me, unless you have some specific reason

Comment: Nested types are ok in the right context. But I think that aliases should be avoided. If you are working on a team and create an alias, will new members, others, be familiar with that? That's not usual, would just create chaos...

Comment: Steven & Bruno, I use this in very defined context, were the type names get so long, that the readiblity heavily decreases. Otherwise I wouldn't choose this solution. It's practically class internal in some sense.

Comment: Jon, well this is of course a good question. I suppose I'll refactor this later when I've a little bit more time. But on the other hand when using library code etc. the occur also frequently situations, were it this aliasing can increase the readability when used carefully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK,

dumb question, quick answer:

```
    namespace A
    {
       using  EC = ClassB.EnumC ; // <- this is the correct definition

       public class ClassB
      {
      ...
```